# A framerate of 30.30 has become common the past couple years. What is it about the number 30.30 that is significant? Why not an even 30, for example?

Tags: framerate

I typically resample the framerate to 30 when I'm encoding (much of my source video was streamed and has unreliable native framerate). But these 30.30 videos I tend to leave at 30.30 just because I don't know why it's like that and don't want to mess with it.

Comment: Never heard of it. I doubt that it’s common, but maybe in a certain niche? What source created the videos? Could your player software be misrepresenting the frame rate? Can you check with an alternate method?

Answer (score 1):

30.30 isn't a standard frame rate. I think you see it a lot because mobile phones (especially iPhones) only "target" certain frame rates, they don't necessarily perfectly deliver them.

https://www.provideocoalition.com/understanding-iphone-framerates-for-shooting-editing-distribution/

Interpreting a 30.30 frame rate video as 30fps won't cause significant issues unless the clip is longer than a few minutes, in which case you may have lip-sync issues with the audio vs the video.

Comment: I don't mind keeping it at 30.30. I just like to know why I'm doing something. It tends to be streaming video, so my current assumption is that some popular software (maybe OBS) defaults to 30.30 or something.

Comment: See this issue I had with Premiere introducing glitches into iPhone footage: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30683/glitches-in-premiere-exports